# Banner Card inside List of items

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to insert a banner card within animated items.

Like the image below.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

- I attempted to use Wrap Widget, but the issue is that my items have animations, and I need to implement lazyLoading (similar to GridView.builder and List.builder) to maintain performance.
- I explored the flutter_staggered_grid_view package, but I encountered the same problem with lazy loading.

Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Post your code here .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.